# How to convert video to html5 animation or slideshow

Tags: html, linux

I tried to convert the video to html5 picture animation, but I don't know how to do it.

[mobamotion](https://mobamotion.mobatek.net/) The following software.  Can only be used on Windows.  I am using linux, is there an alternative product?

[Generated picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no1Wc.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely online converter: `https://converterpoint.com/`